# Do a HTTP get request makes an Idle Session ACTIVE?

Tags: spring-boot, session-timeout, httpsession, spring-session

**Environment Spring Boot, Spring Session, Spring Security**

Hi, I ma implementing session timeout in my spring boot application using the server.servlet.session.timeout=60 . Which means session must timeout after 1 minute of inactivity. Which is not happening. One of the causes would be that my application sends a HTTP GET request (/getCustomerCount() )every 1 second from the webpage (javascript scheduled).

Question : Does HTTP get request converts an IDLE session to be an active session which prevents the sessions to timeout.
If so, then how shall I timeout my application. I want the session idle/active logic to ignore the every second request /getCustomerCount(). Adn if user doesn't perform any task (other than per second request) then consider the session as IDLE and time it out after 60 seconds.

Is there any way in Spring Session, that session manager ignores a particular request while marking a session active and idle ?

Comment: Yep that will refresh session.

Comment: Is there any way in Spring Session, that session manager ignores a particular request while marking a session active and idle ?

Comment: Provide more information about your application - you said you're using Spring Boot, Spring Session and Spring Security but haven't mentioned which versions? Also provide some relevant configuration snippets, most importantly, the ones related to Spring Security and Spring Session.